# How to change textView on one screen from another using button and spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I asked this question before, but instead of explaining what is happening, I'm going to ask how YOU would do this.

**My goal:**

I have 2 screens.

**Screen 1:**
(textview) --> "Choose your favorite number"
(spinner) --> drops down a list of numbers to choose from
(btnGo) --> starts a new intent and changes to screen 2

**screen 2:**
"Your favorite number is:(whatever you selected on the spinner)"

I've tried different ways but i cannot retrieve the information from the spinner after the screens change.

So how would you do this?
As much detail as possible please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this:

In Screen-1 on button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SCREEN2.class);
intent.putExtra("favoriteNumber",GET_SELECTED_SPINNER);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Screen-2 onCreate():

```
String selectedFavorite = getIntent().getStringExtra("favoriteNumber");
YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setText(selectedFavorite);
```

Thatz it.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: for the GET_SELECTED_SPINNER, what do I put in place of that?

Comment: Use this : String selected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what your *"screens"* are so I'm going to assume they are activities.

When you want to pass data from one activity to another, rather than trying to back-reference the activity that called the second one, you should pass into the second activity any data it will need as part of the intent.

E.g.:

```
myIntent.putExtra("spinnerValue", spinner.getIndex());
```

The in the second activity you can read the data:

```
int spinnerValue = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("spinnerValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    your_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {

    selected_number = adapter.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    }
    }

Intent intent = new Intent(screen1.this, screen2.class);
intent.putExtra("selectedNumber", selected_number);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Screen2:

```
String number = this.getIntent.getExtras("selectedNumber");

your_textView.setText(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

well basically when you call for SCREEN2 I presume you run a new intent which will delete all the data you had store.

what you should do is use Shared Preferences [here](http://sogacity.com/using-shared-preferences-in-android/) is a tutorial

or you can make two Layout where you set the first one as `visible` and the other one as `invisible` so that when you click btnGO hide the first layout which contain the spinner and the button and display the new layout that contains the text.

**EDIT:**

first make sure that (textview) (spinner) (btnGo) has a separate layout for example a LinearLayout then another layout for Your favorite number is:(whatever you selected on the spinner)" put them on one xml file only, or if you want you can use `<include />` if you have them in a separate xml file and set the visibility when you perform button click

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
btnGo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

"Your favorite number is:(whatever you selected on thespinner)".setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You get the idea right?

Comment: How would I set the first screen as invisible then?

Comment: first make sure that `(textview) (spinner) (btnGo)` has a separate layout for example a `LinearLayout` then another layout for `Your favorite number is:(whatever you selected on the spinner)"` and set the visibility when you perform button click

`spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
`btnGo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
`textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

`"Your favorite number is:(whatever you selected on the spinner)".setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

//In screen1 button event

Screen2 sc2 = new Screen2();

sc2.Set(3);

//******

//Screen2 class

class Screen2
{

```
  private int i;
  public int Get(){
  return i;

   public void Set( int a )
   this.i = a;
```

}